# Is there any way to insert a custom class in an existing inheritance tree?

Tags: java, android

I’m working on an android application that currently has two Activities, A and B, that have some code in common, their options menu and some other code.  To cut down on copying and pasting, I created a class called BaseActivity that extends Activity with the, and I then had A and B extend BaseActivity.  At least that’s what I wanted to do, but I ran into a problem.  While A now extends BaseActivity just fine, I can't figure out how to make B extend BaseActivity because it's not just an activity, it’s a MapActivity.  So it’s inheritance tree looks like this:

MapActivity inheritance tree:

```
java.lang.Object
   android.content.Context
       android.content.ContextWrapper
           android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               android.app.Activity
                   com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
```

But in order for it to inherit my code, I’d need to make it look like this:

```
java.lang.Object
   android.content.Context
       android.content.ContextWrapper
           android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               android.app.Activity
                  mypackage.BaseActivity
                     com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
```

Is there any way to insert my custom class in an inheritance tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. It's hard to say exactly what the best approach would be here, but I would at least *try* to use composition instead of inheritance. Can you implement a separate non-activity object and use one of those from both A and B?

Comment: He should indeed use composition and create shared UI and related stuff in seperate classes. An activity can then hold a member of that specific feature. Easier and a more cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

Well since your code is really a MapActivity it should extend that (assuming you don't want to do composition).  If you want to do composition make your class have a reference to MapActivity which will allow you to interact with that class.